# Examples of conversion from bidirectional to unidirectional torques/forces and vice versa

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am looking for examples in which bidirectional torques or forces are converted or could be converted to unidirectional torques or forces. The torques/forces can also be mixed (e.g. a unidirectional torque converted to a bidirectional force).

E.g.

- wave power (bidirectional force is converted to a unidirectional
  torque, depending on the design)
- pistion engine/motor (bidirectional
  force is converted to a unidirectional torque)
- pistion compressor/pump (unidirectional torque is converted to a
  bidirectional force)

**Edit (2023/09/27):**

Added clarification based on the comments: The torques and forces in the conversion shall be able to provide useful work (input or output). I am aware of reaction forces/torques. In the examples I am looking for bidirectional motion (energy) should be converted to a unidirection motion (energy) or vice versa.

Thanks for any input.

Best regards,
Daniel

Comment: Turn them into vectors and add the vectors...this happens in any moderately rigid body

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I am not looking for a way to calculate the motion. I am looking for physical examples in which a machine of any kind converts a bidirectional motion into unidirectional motion or vice versa.

Comment: "For every force there is an equal and opposite reaction"...

Comment: "piston engine" has torque reaction - seen in trucks pulling hard with chassis twisting and in fighter aircraft...

Comment: I am aware of reaction forces. Please see my edited question. The torques/forces shall be able to provide useful work. In a piston engine, the reaction torque does not provide useful work. I am sure there are other examples than a pistion engine, in which bidirectional motion (energy input) is converted to a unidirectional motion (energy output) or vice versa.